# PxFusion DPS Payment Express

Tags: magento-1.8, payment, payment-gateway, payment-methods

I am looking for Px Fusion extensions for my online store. any suggestions ?

Comment: You are looking for "Payment Express".

Comment: yes, looking for payment express px fusion. if there anyone guide to me how should i write for code. thx.

Answer (score 5):

Here's the PxFusion done by official DPS partner. It has just been released recently http://www.moustacherepublic.com/payment-express-dps-pxfusion.html

Answer (score 4):

I am the developer behind the free [Magebase DPS](https://github.com/fooman/magebase_paymentexpress/) extension which offers support for PxPost and PxPay/PxPay2.0.

We also offer a pro version, which is commercial, which now supports PxFusion as a fully integrated payment option:
[image: PxFusion checkout]

I am currently not aware of any alternatives. For a link and the overview from DPS see [their website](http://www.paymentexpress.com/Partners/Shopping_Cart/Magento).

Comment: thanks your offer. but U$260.00 is expensive for me.

Answer (score 4):

Step one for **any** payment extension is: Ask the payment processor themselves how to integrate with Magento.  Chances are they've gotten the question before and can point you towards some options.

Step two is to search through [Magento Connect](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/catalogsearch/result/?id=&s=7&pl=0&hp=0&q=DPS&t=0&p=1) for an extension.   It looks like [there](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/fooman-dps-pro.html) are [two](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/dps-paymentexpress-by-magebase.html) that fit your criteria.